# Regex to match everything after the last occurrence of a string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Struggling to find a way to do this so any help appreciated.

**Have simple text on single line - and want to match all of the text after the final `</p>` tag.**

I'm using regex in Open Office - so I need to return a direct match rather than a javascript array.

String looks like this:

```
<p>Foo bar bar bar foo</p> <p>Foo bar bar foo</p> This Foo bar foo bar <br>
```

I can match INCLUDING the final `</p>` like this:

```
<\/p>(?!.*<\/p>).*$
```

I can match it in php regex flavour like this:

```
(?<=<\/p>(?!.*<\/p>))(.*)(?=$)
```

And I can get close using this - but it only matches at the first `<` - not the whole `</p>` string:

```
(?!.*<\/p>)(.*)(?=$)
```

Driving me crazy so any help appreciated.

Thanks

Sorry - yes did see the duplicate question but couldn't get it to work - so they said these solutions for their problem:

```
.*\[\/quote\](.*)$

[\s\S]*\[\/quote\]([\s\S]*)$
```

Which I transposed to my problem to look like this:

```
.*<\/p>(.*)$

[\s\S]*<\/p>([\s\S]*)$
```

Neither of which I could get to work with open office regex - so hence the question.

Comment: Just for the record I ended up with this:
(?s)(?!.*?<\/p>)[^<\/p>].*$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I did not catch you wanted after:

```
</p>
```

Using this:

```
.*<\/p>(.*)$
```

You have an array where the second element is what you look for.

Tested code:

```
var text = '<p>Foo bar bar bar foo</p> <p>Foo bar bar foo</p> This Foo bar foo bar <br>';
var patt = new RegExp(".*<\/p>(.*)$");
var matched = patt.exec(text);
```

Tester:

http://www.pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - yes I know this one works - but I want to match AFTER  the final </p> - this regex INCLUDES it.

Comment: Thank you.
This works fine in your javascript tester - but my regex tester seems to suggest it won't work for javascript:
https://regex101.com/r/uR0pO9/2
I will just do a bit more testing today and make sure it's working in my instance then mark as correct all being well.
Much appreciated.

Comment: OK I get it now - However I need a direct match rather than a js array I'm afraid - I only specified js as that appears to be the regex engine in the system I'm using (as neither the prce or python code above works).
My fault for not being specific enough in the question so I will try and amend it. Thanks again.

Comment: @SpecialK The JavaScript RegEx object methods will always return an array. You can get the captured group from matched[1]

Comment: @MattSizzle yes it returns always an array, also if it was a single match Special K should work on element [0],

Comment: @WhiteFeather Actually [0] is always the full string compared against. You always want to use element[1] as it contains the 1st captured group.